Spring security and camunda: JWT + login page
I have an existing Spring boot app (3.x), which serves endpoints protected by JWT with Spring Security. I have added Camunda to this app (Camunda 7 with spring boot starter) but currently I'm unable to acces Camunda's UI because of our current Spring security configuration.
The existing security config for JWT with a SecurityFilterChain + a JWTAuthenticationFilter =>
@Bean
public JWTAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    List<RequestMatcher> listeMatch = new ArrayList<>();
    listeMatch.add(new NegatedRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/index.html")));
    listeMatch.add(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**"));

    RequestMatcher requestMatcher = new AndRequestMatcher(listeMatch);
    JWTAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter = new JWTAuthenticationFilter(requestMatcher);
    jwtAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    jwtAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new JWTAuthenticationSuccessHandler());
    return jwtAuthenticationFilter;
}
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, JWTAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(custo -> custo.requestMatchers("/public/**")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated())
        .addFilterAfter(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    return http.build();
}
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)
        .authenticationProvider(jwtAuthenticationProvider)
        .build();
}

I've tried to configure another SecurityFilterChain in my application, but I'm unable to make both configuration work in parallel (if I comment out one of them, the other one is working).
Important note: the existing JWT config is inside a library shared between ~30 applications, so any modifications inside should be minor.
The configuration for Camunda UI that I did for now:
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain camundaSecurityFilterChain(final HttpSecurity httpSec,
    @Qualifier("camundaAuthentProvider") final AuthenticationProvider provider)
    throws Exception {

    return httpSec
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->
            authorize
                .requestMatchers("/camunda/app/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated())
        .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
        .authenticationProvider(provider)
        .build();
}

@Bean(name = "camundaAuthentProvider")
public AuthenticationProvider buildAuthenticationProvider(
    @Qualifier("camundaUserDetailsSvc") final UserDetailsService service,
    @Qualifier("camundaPwdEncoder") final PasswordEncoder encoder) {

    final DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(service);
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder);
    return authProvider;
}
@Bean("camundaUserDetailsSvc")
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(
    @Qualifier("camundaBpmDataSource") final DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcUserDetailsManager(dataSource);
}
@Bean("camundaPwdEncoder")
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}


I tried to add some @Order on the SecurityFilterChains but it didn't fix the problem.
How can I have those two configurations work together, one for the camunda UI and the other one for REST API ?
